# Given a list of integers, some of which may be negative, extract the pair that sums to the 2 maximum numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Is there any solution beside O(n2) .
I was thinking about looping through every value and then get the sum

Comment: Uhm, the two largest numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pair which is made from the 2 largest elements sum to the largest number. Just find the 2 largest elements and sum them - it is `O(n)`

For general `k` elements that sum to the largest number, you can use [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to find the k largest element, and then with a 2nd iteration - sum all elements greater then it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the two largest numbers, you only need  one loop, which would make the algorithm `O(n)` not `O(n^2)`.

If you require more complex pair analysis perform a quicksort on the integers `O(n log n)`, then you can just pick the two largest numbers which will be the largest pair and any other pair combination you so desire.